# Image Of a Discontinuous linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to show, Image of  $unit~ disc$ under a discontinuous linear functional from a Normed Linear Space is $\mathbb{C}$ . I know the Image is Unbounded

Comment: What it is $unit dis$? Is it the unit sphere or the unit ball?

Comment: ${x\in X : ||x|| \le 1}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: a discontinuous linear functional is still linear!  So if $f(x)=z$, consider $f(wx)$, where $|w|=1$.